# Unable to fetch the data from spring boot app in React app

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I am working on linking spring boot app and React app but unfortunately while fetching the data from boot app, I am encountering errors as mentioned below.

AppCrypto.js:22 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/secretdata/allcurrency/ 403

crypto:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/secretdata/allcurrency/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Below are the code snippets.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Jumbotron,Button,Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

class AppCrypto extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {currencies: null};
}



componentDidMount() {
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  };
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/secretdata/allcurrency/',requestOptions)
        .then(results => {
          return results.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          let currencies =data.results.map((curr) =>{
            return(
              <Table>
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>CURRENCY_NAME</th>
                    <th>CURRENCY_TICKER</th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <td>{curr.id}</td>
                       <td>{curr.currencyname}</td>
                       <td>{curr.currencyticker}</td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </Table>
            )
          })
          this.setState({currencies:currencies});
          console.log("state",this.state.currencies);
})

}

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container2">
        <div className="container1">
         {this.state.currencies}
        </div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}



export default AppCrypto;
```

```
package de.ohmstr.secretdata;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/secretdata/")
public class SecretDataController {

    @Autowired
    private SecretDataRepository sdr;

    @PostMapping (path="/currency/")
    public @ResponseBody String retrievCurrency(@RequestParam String currencyname, @RequestParam String currencyticker){

        SecretData sd=new SecretData();
        sd.setCurrencyname(currencyname);
        sd.setCurrencyticker(currencyticker);
        sdr.save(sd);
        return "saved";
    }

    @GetMapping (path="/allcurrency/")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<SecretData> getAllCurrencies(){
        return sdr.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping (path="/getmessage/")
    public @ResponseBody String getMessage(){
        return "Welcome to my Secret World";
    }



}
```

Comment: Since your backend is on a different port, it's basically considered a different domain. You can setup a proxy to forward the requests to the correct port using your backend. If you're using `create-react-app`, see the [docs about proxies here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Comment: Thank you for proxy hint. I have added proxy in package.json and I get the below error.
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
(anonymous function)
F:/secret/secretapp/src/components/AppCrypto.js:20
  17 |   return results.json();
  18 | })
  19 | .then(data => {
> 20 |   let currencies =data.results.map((curr) =>{
     | ^  21 |     return(
  22 |       <Table>
  23 |          <thead>

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting currencies as undefined, I hope you have made sure you get data but as console throwing error, at some point you might get it undefined. 
I am just adding condition to your .then handler as,

```
let currencies =(data.results || []).map((curr)
=>{ return( <Table> <thead> <tr> <th>ID</th>
<th>CURRENCY_NAME</th>
<th>CURRENCY_TICKER</th> </tr> </thead> 
<tbody>
 <tr> <td>{curr.id}</td> <td>{curr.currencyname}
</td>
 <td>{curr.currencyticker}</td> </tr> </tbody>
 </Table> ) }) 
this.setState({currencies:currencies}, ()=>{ 
 console.log(this.state));
```

Comment: I have modified the code as mentioned below.But I am getting the error as 

error:
-------

  43 |    <th>CURRENCY_TICKER</th>
  44 |   </tr>
  45 | </thead>
> 46 | <tbody>
     | ^  47 | {this.state.currencies.map(function(item, key){
  48 |     return(
  49 |       <tr key={key}>

Updated code:
----

  {this.state.currencies.map(function(item, key){
            return(
              <tr key={key}>
                 <td>item.id</td>
                 <td>item.currencyname</td>
                 <td>item.currencyticker</td>
              </tr>
            )
        })}